# Sox bad input format. Sampling rate was not specified

Tags: sox

I have the following sox script to split an audio file in which I do specificy the sample rate, but still it throws the error "sampling rate not specified":

sox input.raw output.raw trim 0 10800 : newfile : restart -r 48000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are positional.  The syntax is like this:

> ```
> sox [global-options] [format-options] infile1
> [[format-options] infile2] ... [format-options] outfile
> [effect [effect-options]] ...
> ```
>
> https://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

so if options `-r 48000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1` all apply to `input.raw` then you want something like this:

```
sox -r 48000 -e signed -b 16 -c 1 input.raw output.raw trim 0 10800 : newfile : restart
```